# Does Visual C++ 2010 Beta 1 have unique_ptr, and if not, where can I get a C++0x reference implementation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++, unique-ptr

I do know:

- It wasn't in the CTP
- It's slated to be in the final release
- I can't find it in Beta 1
- I want to play with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the same header as shared_ptr :

```
#include <memory>
```

Comment: Why couldn't I find it before?! Madness. It's definitely there!